# Ajax call returning int instead of string in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

This is my model. get items will get the item name from the database according to location

```
class Itemsale_db extends CI_Model

    public function getItems($userid,$loc)
        {
            $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Name from itransfile where";

            if (is_numeric($loc))
                $sql .= " location_id = ".$loc;
            else 
                $sql .= " location_id IN(SELECT location_id FROM client_locations where client_id = " .$userid. ")";

            $query = $this->db->query($sql);        
            $item = $query->result_array();
                return $item;
        }
}
```

This is my controller. getItemsAjax will call the model and return the json encoded array to view.

```
class ItemSale extends CI_Controller {

public function getItemsAjax($userid,$locid)
        {
            $this->load->model('itemsale_db');
             header('Content-Type: application/x-json; charset=utf-8');
             $item = $this->itemsale_db->getItems($userid,$locid);
             echo json_encode($item);
        }
}
```

Here is the Javascript. loc is the location selection box and items is the item selection box

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#loc').change(function(){ 
            $("#items > option").remove(); 
            var opt = $('<option />');
            opt.val('All');
            opt.text('All');
             $('#items').append(opt);
            var loc_id = $('#loc').val(); 
            var userid = "<?php echo $this->session->userdata('userid'); ?>";

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url()?>" + "index.php/itemsale/getItemsAjax/"+loc_id + "/"+userid, 

                success: function(item) 
                {
                $.each(item,function(Name) 
                {

                    var opt = $('<option />');
                    opt.val(Name);
                    opt.text(Name);
                    $('#items').append(opt); 
                });
                }

            });         

    });
 });
```

Ajax call returning me list of integers instead of items name. 
[image]
[image]

console.log(item)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code issue is this(Format of [**$.each**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function is incorrect).

> First argument should be index and second should be value in *$.each*
>   callback.

This is correct format of `$.each` callback `Function( Integer indexInArray, Object value )`

Use following code in ajax success:

```
$.each(item,function(index,Name) {//added index first and then value
    var opt = $('<option />');
    opt.val(Name);
    opt.text(Name);
    $('#items').append(opt); 
});
```

**Note:** While you are using only single parameter in each callback its treating `Name` ad `Index`.